# htm5 input type color and jquery

Tags: jquery, html

ok i have the following code,button and whe i press it i create divs and i want when dblclick
on the divs input type color to show and to change the color of the div dinamically but without button.The problem is with the selectors i tryed with change,submit but it`s now working.Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #toolbar{
                width:600px;height: 100px;border: 3px solid;
                position: absolute;left: 350px;
            }
            #buttons{
                position: relative;top:15px;left:150px;
            }
            #ButtonElement{
                width: 600px;border: 3px solid;position: absolute;top:200px;
                height: 600px;
            }
            #TextElement{
                 width: 600px;border: 3px solid;position: absolute;top:200px;left:700px;
                height: 600px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <div id="buttons">
            <button id="Button">Create Element Button</button>
            <button id="Text">Create Element Text</button></div>
        </div>
        <div id="ButtonElement"><h2>Elements Button</h2></div>
        <div id="TextElement"><h2>Elements Text</h2></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
        <script>
         //   function Toolbar(){
          //      this.render=function(){
           //         $('body').append("<div id='toolbar'></div>");
          //      };
          //      this.init=function(){
          //          $("#toolbar").append("<div id='buttons'></div>");
          //      };
          //      this.createButton=function(){

          //      };
          //  }
             var Colors=[];
          var count=0;
         function Button(count){
    this.background=null;
    this.count=count;
     this.render=function(){

         $("#ButtonElement").append("<div id=div" + this.count +">Nqkakav Tekst</div>");
    };

}

Button.prototype.setBackground=function(background){
    this.background=background;
};
Button.prototype.getBackground=function(){
    return this.background;
};

$("#Button").click(function(){
    count++;
    var b=new Button(count);
    b.render();
  $("#div"+ count).dblclick(function(){
  var diva=this;
   $(this).append("<span id='colorchange'><input type='color' id='color' name='favcolor'></span>");
  $("#color").change(function(){

    var value=$("#color").val();  
   cssChange(diva,value);
    });enter code here

});
});


            </script>
    </body>
</html>

so I just want when click on some of the divs colorpicker to show and when i click on some color to change the background of the div.
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use active: and when the div is active using .click

Comment: #ButtonElement:active{
                width: 600px;border: 3px solid;position: absolute;top:200px;
                height: 600px;
            }